# Java error for beginner

Tags: java

I just start learning Java. I write a program like this:

Bacteria.class

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Bacteria extends Creature{

public static final int COLOR_STEP = 256/MAX_AGE;
Bacteria(Board board, int _x, int _y){


    super.board = board;
    //initialize age, x, y
    super.age = 1;
    super.x = _x;
    super.y = _y;
}

//Draw a circle representing the creature at its position
//This function is done.

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(0, COLOR_STEP * age, 0));
    g.fillOval(x * board.CELL_SIZE, y * board.CELL_SIZE, board.CELL_SIZE, board.CELL_SIZE);
}
public void tick() {
    //your code
    // this is how the creature lives in one tick
    // make the creature get older if it is not dead.
    // if it's got older than MAX_AGE then it should die
    // ...call board.addDead() to register the dead creature
    // if it can have baby then try reproduce()
    age++;
    if (this.canHaveBaby()) {
        this.reproduce();
    }
    //this.reproduce();
    if (age > MAX_AGE) {
        board.addDead(this);
    }
}
}
```

Creature.class

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Creature {
public static final int MAX_AGE = 5;
public Board board;

public int age; // age of the creature measures in ticks
public int x; // (x,y) is the position of the creature
public int y;

Creature(Board board, int _x, int _y) {
    this.board = board;
    //initialize age, x, y
    age = 1;
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
}

public Creature() {
}


//Draw a circle representing the creature at its position
//This function is done.
public void draw(Graphics g){}

public void tick(){}

public void reproduce() {
    //your code
    // if it can have a baby then produce a baby
    // ...in an empty cell next to its cell.
    // board.emptyCell() should be used
    // ....to check whether a cell in the board is empty
    // and call board.addBaby() to place the baby to the board
    //int x_current = x, y_current = y;
    if(board.emptyCell(x, y+1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x, y+1);
        //System.out.println("1");
        board.addBaby( baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x+1,y)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x+1, y);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x+1,y+1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x+1, y+1);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x-1,y)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x-1, y);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x,y-1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x, y-1);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x-1,y-1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x-1, y-1);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x-1,y+1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x-1, y+1);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
    else if(board.emptyCell(x+1,y-1)){
        Creature baby = new Creature(board,x+1, y-1);
        board.addBaby(baby);
    }
}

public boolean canHaveBaby() {
    //your code
    // if the creature is dead or it is too young
    // then it cannot have a baby
    if(age == 0 || age > MAX_AGE){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean atPosition(int _x, int _y) {
    //your code
    // return true if the creature is at the position (_x,_y)
    // you need this function for board.empty to function correctly
    if(_x == x && _y == y){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Board.class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Board extends JPanel {

public static final int CELL_SIZE = 10;
private final int rows = 10;
private final int cols = 20;
ArrayList<Creature> creatureList;

ArrayList<Creature> babies, dead;
// ArrayList<Bacteria> bacteriaList;
// ArrayList<Bacteria> babies_bac, dead_bac;
Board() {
    super();
    setBackground(Color.white);
    creatureList = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    //creatureList.size();
    babies = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    dead = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cols * CELL_SIZE, rows * CELL_SIZE));
    creatureList.add(new Bacteria(this, 1, 1));
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Creature creature: creatureList) {
        creature.draw(g);
    }
}

public void tick() {
    dead = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    babies = new ArrayList<Creature>();

    for (Creature creature: creatureList) {
         creature.tick();
    }
    creatureList.addAll(babies);
    creatureList.removeAll(dead);
}

public void addBaby(Creature baby) {
    if (baby != null) babies.add(baby);
}

public void addDead(Creature deadCreature) {
    if (deadCreature != null) dead.add(deadCreature);
}

public boolean emptyCell(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= cols || y >= rows) return false;

    for (Creature creature : creatureList) {
        if (creature.atPosition(x, y)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (Creature creature : creatureList) {
        if (creature.atPosition(x, y)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public String getPopulation() {
    return String.format("%d", creatureList.size());
}
}
```

and BacteriaSimulator.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class BacteriaSimulator extends JFrame {
private Board board;
private JLabel label;

public BacteriaSimulator() {
    initUI();
    setTitle("Bacteria Simulator");
    setSize(350, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void initUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    board = new Board();
    panel.add(board);

    label = new JLabel(board.getPopulation());
    panel.add(label);

    JButton button = new JButton("Tick");
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonNextListener());
    panel.add(button);

    add(panel);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BacteriaSimulator ex = new BacteriaSimulator();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private class ButtonNextListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        board.tick();
        label.setText(board.getPopulation());
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

I want Board.class work with creatureList. However, Board is still initialized with a bacteria `(creatureList.add(new Bacteria(this, 1, 1));)`. I got a problem that is Board.class can not run draw() and tick() method which I want. How to draw objects bacteria and make the right method of tick ()? Can you help me! Thank you!

Comment: _`I got a problem that is Board.class can not run draw() and tick() method which I want`_ - What's the problem? Do you get an compile time error? Or an Exception?

Comment: I assume you meant .java not .class for your file extensions?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your draw() and tick() functions are part of Bacteria.java. They cannot be used from Board.java unless you create an instance of Bacteria and then invoke the methods using that.

Comment: The OP calls the method `creature.draw(g);` so I assume he has a object

Comment: I want to create another class Ant.java which has different color to Bacteria and inherits Creature class and can draw it on the board with bacteria. How can I? Can you help me! Thank you!